# Servlet-Cannot get a list in doGet methos

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

I wanted to create a servlet that shows Studentlist which is from SQL Server. However, when I click show button the server returns:

> HTTP Status 500 - Cannot invoke "model.StudentList.getList()" because "list" is null

controller.StudentServlet.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.Student;
import model.StudentList;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class StudentServlet
 */
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public StudentServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StudentList list = null;
        try {
            list = new StudentList();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<Student> myStudents = list.getList();
        request.setAttribute("MYSTUDENTS", myStudents);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

model.StudentList.java

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentList {
    private static ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public StudentList() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Workshop1";
        String user = "quan167";
        String pass = "12345";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
        int id = 0;
        String name = "";
        String gender = "";
        String date = "";
        String sql = "select * from Student";

        try {

            p = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = p.executeQuery();
            // Condition check
            while (rs.next()) {

                id = rs.getInt("id");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                gender = rs.getString("gender");
                date = rs.getString("dob");
                list.add(new Student(id, name, gender, date));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

and model.Student.java which has: id(int), name(String), gender(String), dob(String) stands for date of birth.

But this works out just fine in this test class

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tst {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Workshop1";
        String user = "quan167";
        String pass = "12345";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

        StudentList list = null;
        try {
            list = new StudentList();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<Student> myStudents = list.getList();
        System.out.println(myStudents);


    }
}
```

Anyone knows the solution? Thank you.

Edit: I knew where the problem is. So basically I have not put the sqlijdbc4.jar in WEB-INF.lib

Comment: Look for the stack trace that comes from an SQLException.  Swallowing the exception then continuing on is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Remove your catch blocks and let the exception be reported by your web server.

Comment: @tgdavies I have but it still shows the same error

Comment: There is only one way that `list` can be `null` at the point you call `getList()`: If an exception was thrown in the block where you assign a value to `list`. You need to see what that exception is.

Comment: @tgdavies thank you ! I did what you said and turns out the problem is "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://l". So I managed to find out that put the sqlijdbc4.jar under WEB-INF.lib  solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Change the following lines:**

```
 public class StudentList {
     private static ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

**to these lines:**

```
public class StudentList {
    public ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem as far as I can see. Can you explain?

Comment: this does not solve this problem. I have the same project but not connected to MSSQL and it runs without any error

Comment: and I think it won't have anything to do with the problem because the getList() method is public

Comment: @QuanLeAnh It was the STATIC word works. As you use your list in a new instance, so the list must NOT be static to class.